# perldoc does not display text between section

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I have this POD file:

```
=head1 Create professional slideshows with Mojolicious::Plugin::RevealJS


=head2 Install and run a Mojolicious server

Santa's elf had a problem. He had to write very fast a presentation and show it to a bunch of new elf's.
The email assigning this to him was sent by Santa himself.
The elf started to look on Metacpan and found this module: L<Mojolicious::Plugin::RevealJS|https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::RevealJS>

He quickly typed the following commands:

C<cpanm Mojolicius Mojolicious::Plugin::RevealJS>

Now he could generate an mojo lite app using:

C<mojo generate lite-app slide_show>

Because the elf was trained in the ancient arts  of the elders
he cloud open new file with vim and paste this code in:

=begin perl

use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;

app->static->paths(['.']);

plugin 'RevealJS';

any '/' => { template => 'presentation', layout => 'revealjs' };

app->start;

=end perl
```

When I run `perldoc t.pod`, the code between '=begin perl' and '=end perl' is not visible. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You might want to just indent the code bits once (as in, a few spaces, or one tab).

Comment: Also this looks like it should be a Perl Advent calendar entry. We're still missing a few. https://cfp.perladvent.org/

Comment: for Perl Advent calendar it is :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [perlpod documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod#=begin-formatname) says ...

> For, begin, and end will let you have regions of text/code/data that are not generally interpreted as normal Pod text, but are passed directly to particular formatters, or are otherwise special. A formatter that can use that format will use the region, otherwise it will be completely ignored.

The *formatter* in this case is the thing that `perldoc` uses to render your POD into text. I suspect it doesn't know what to do with the format `perl`, so it ignores it.

A formatter that produces HTML might know what to do with the `perl` format, and might replace this with a code block that has syntax highlighting.

If you want your code examples in the POD to always show up as code, use a [verbatim paragraph](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod#Verbatim-Paragraph) instead. This is done by adding indentation at the front.

```perl
=head2 frobnicate($foo)

This function frobnicates the C<$foo>.

    my $bar = frobnicate($foo)

=cut

sub frobnicate { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

The description of a `=begin <format>`/`=end <format>` in [perlpod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod) starts by saying this:

> =begin formatname
> =end formatname
> =for formatname text...
>
> For, begin, and end will let you have regions of text/code/data that are not generally interpreted as normal Pod text, but are passed directly to particular formatters, or are otherwise special. A formatter that can use that format will use the region, otherwise it will be completely ignored.

Anything between `=begin perl` and `=end perl` is ignored by the standard Pod formatter and will only be processed by a specialised "perl" formatter (and no such formatter exists in the standard Perl toolset - you'd need to write your own).

You don't say what you expect this syntax to achieve, but it seems likely that you're looking for a verbatim paragraph.

> **Verbatim Paragraph**
>
> Verbatim paragraphs are usually used for presenting a codeblock or other text which does not require any special parsing or formatting, and which shouldn't be wrapped.
>
> A verbatim paragraph is distinguished by having its first character be a space or a tab. (And commonly, all its lines begin with spaces and/or tabs.) It should be reproduced exactly, with tabs assumed to be on 8-column boundaries. There are no special formatting codes, so you can't italicize or anything like that. A \ means \, and nothing else.